# how change the data column to timestamp format using pd.Timestamp function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

In python I have a data set with these columns:

```
ID_Order    ID_Customer ID_Item DateTime_CartFinalize   Amount_Gross_Order  city_name_fa    Quantity_item
```

It is for more than 200000 transactions. 
I am going to use association rules. At the first step, I have to Change the `DateTime_CartFinalize` column to timestamp format using `pd.Timestamp` function. Before that, ensure that the date format in your `digiasso.csv` file is in this `2/11/18 12:29 AM` format.
 Hint: use the aggregate function. 
???

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a *DateFrame* with *DateTime_CartFinalize* column of
*String* type (actually *object*).

Then you can convert this column calling:

```
df.DateTime_CartFinalize = pd.to_datetime(df.DateTime_CartFinalize)
```

*pd.to_datetime* is clever enough to recognize the actual format of source data.
Or you can use *dayfirst*, *yearfirst* or *format* parameters to pass a hint
how to convert the source string.
Read the documentation of this function.

Yet another option:
If you read your DataFrame with e.g. *read_csv*, then use *parse_dates*
parameter, passing indices or names of columns which should be converted
to dates, as early as at the reading step.

Comment: At the first glance it looks OK. Try and check the result.

Comment: df.DateTime_CartFinalize=df.DateTime_CartFinalize.agg(pd.Timestamp) , is it corret too?

Comment: I want to add a new column named year and put the year of each transaction in it. I want to use the “lambda” to define a function and apply it to all elements using the “agg” function.  I wrote this, but I got an error:  df.yearr=df.DateTime_CartFinalize.agg(lambda x: x.year)

Comment: I know another way with interval :                                                                                 
    >>>     def interval(x):
             interval=(x.year)
             return(interval)

    >>>     df['year']=df['DateTime_CartFinalize'].agg(interval)

Comment: I tried your code and got no error, but I started with *df['yearr'] = ...*
(maybe the source of your error is that *yearr* column does not exist yet,
so you can not use the "dot notation").
On the other hand, *agg* is used rather with *groupy*.
A more intuitive solution is e.g. *df['yearr'] = df.DateTime_CartFinalize.dt.year*.